# Showing that the closure of a subset of a closed set is going to remain a subset of the closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

It is clear intuitively that the closure of a subset of a closed set will remain a subset of the original closed set. However, I am struggling to prove that this is the case. More explicitly, I would like to address the following:

> **Question:** Show that the closure of a subset of a closed set is going to remain a subset of the closed set

For example, in a problem I have been working on, I have been trying to show that $$[0,1] \subset \mathcal{cl} (A) \space \text{ for }  A := \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$$

We already know that the following holds: $$\mathcal{cl}( \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]) = \bigcap\limits_{\delta > 0} A_{\delta} \space \space \text{ for } A_{\delta} = \bigcup\limits_{x \in A} B(x, \delta)$$ where $B(a,r)$ is a ball of radius $r$ centered at $a$.

This reduces the problem down to one of set manipulations, but I am struggling to construct a proof that inclusion holds (despite having a good intuition for it).

I have managed to show that the converse inclusion holds, however, I am trying to show equality here, and so I need to show this other inclusion direction to complete the argument.

---

I would be grateful for any assistance or references that could help here. To clarify, I would like to show this using the definition of the closure specified above.

Comment: What's the definition of a closed set?  What's the definition of a closure of a set?  If closed means "contains all its limit points" and if closure means "including its limit points" this reduces to showing any limit point of a sets closure is a limit point of the set as well.... this can be done by taking a notably small neighborhood around a point in the nbrhd of the limit point so that the smaller neighborhood is entirely contained in the neighborhood of the limit point.

Comment: That definition of a closed set is correct. However, the definition of the closure that I am using is the intersection of $A_{\delta}$ over $\delta > 0$ (as used in the question) @fleablood

Comment: How could it not be.  Suppose $x\in cl(A)$ but $x\not \in [0,1]$.  If $x > 1$ then let $\delta = x-1> 0$.  Now consider *any* $a \in A$ then $d(a,x) > \delta$ so $x \not \in B(a,\delta)$ for *any* $a\in A$.  So $x \not\in cl(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets containing it, so the closure of a set is a subset of any closed set containing it.

Using the suggestion of @Aaron, and your definition of $cl(A)$ in some metric topology:

Part 2)
\begin{align*}
A \text{ closed} &\implies \forall y \notin A \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad B(y,\delta) \cap A = \emptyset \\
&\implies \forall y \notin A \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \forall x \in A \quad B(x,\delta/2) \cap B(y,\delta/2) = \emptyset \\
&\implies \forall y \notin A \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad y \notin A_{\delta/2} \\
&\implies \forall y \notin A \quad y \notin cl(A) \\
&\implies cl(A) \subset A\\
\end{align*}

Since we always have $A \subset cl(A)$, which follows easily from the definition of $cl(A)$ that we're using, this gives us: $A \text{ closed} \implies cl(A)=A$.

Part 3)

$A \subset B \implies \forall \delta > 0 \quad A_\delta \subset B_\delta \implies cl(A) \subset cl(B)$

Using these two parts, we get that if $A$ is a subset of a closed set $B$, then $cl(A) \subset cl(B) = B$

Comment: Can we prove this property from the definition of the closure that I am working with in the question? (where we define the closure to be the intersection over $\delta >0$ of $A_{\delta}$)

Comment: @FD_bfa Maybe you can break things up into three parts: the closure of any set is closed, the closure of a closed set is itself, and if $A\subset B$, then $cl(A)\subset cl(B)$.  With those three facts, it shouldn't be too bad to show the property Joe mentions, or to approach it otherwise.